# PHP: посчитать количество прослушиваний трека

Tags: php

На сайте выводится список треков, как можно считать прослушивания для каждого трека?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда человек нажимает на кнопку начала прослушивания, посылаем ajax-запрос на сервер, где говорим, что началось прослушивание такого-то трека. В базе увеличиваем счетчик прослушивания для конкретного трека.

Если трек подгружается после нажатия, то можно перед началом загрузки увеличить счетчик.

как-то так

Answer (score 4):

Какой вопрос такой ответ: `jQuery/ajax`

---

И не надо минусы ставить) тут телепатов нет, поэтому угадать как вы проигрываете треки и всякое другое мы не можем знать...

---

Основной смысл в том, чтобы отследить нажатие кнопки `play` либо окончания проигрывания файла (смотря что считать "прослушиванием") и записать это в базу. для этого проще всего будет использовать `ajax`-запросы.